# Converti un Resulset a Un Objeto al devolver el objeto me devuelve una NullPointerException? con JDBC

Tags: java

```
public TaxCategory findByName(int taxId) {
         TaxCategory taxCategory=null;
         Statement stmt = null;
         ResultSet rst = null;
                Connection acceDB = conexion.getConexion();

      String query ="Select *  from tax_categories where tax_category_id=" + taxId;
  try{
             stmt = acceDB.createStatement();


      rst =  stmt.executeQuery(query);

                       if(rst.next()){
             taxCategory= new TaxCategory();
             taxCategory.setTaxCategoryId(rst.getInt("tax_category_id"));
             taxCategory.setTaxCategoryName(rst.getString("tax_category_name")); 
             } else {
                                  }

  }catch(SQLException | java.lang.NullPointerException ex ){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
  } finally{
         try {
             if(rst !=null){
                 rst.close();
             }

         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(TaxCategoryDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

         if(stmt != null){
             try {
                stmt.close();
             } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(TaxCategoryDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
         }
  }

    return taxCategory;  
 }
```

ahora voy a usar la funcion con un JList

```
frmTax.jList1.addListSelectionListener((ListSelectionEvent e) ->{

     Tax tax = null;
     TaxCategory taxCategory = null;

    frmTax.jList1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);



      tax = (Tax) frmTax.jList1.getSelectedValue();



         taxCategory = modeloTaxCategory.findByName(tax.getTax_category_id());
    frmTax.jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(taxCategory);




     });
```

Comment: En que parte te arroja el error?

Comment: rst =  stmt.executeQuery(query);

Comment: el problema es que funciona bien unas 5 veces a la 6 falla de forma aleatoria

Comment: Estoy bastante familiarizado con el error de _NullPointerException_ , significa que estas intentando acceder a un objeto que aún no has creado. Puede que lo hayas nombrado pero tienes que instanciarlo, es decir, crear el objeto aunque este bacio, solo con el nombramiento no lo consigues

Comment: si tienes razon pero el problema que provocaba eso que comentas es que  no cerre la conexion a la DB Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto taxCategory que creas a null ,lo inicializas dentro del `if`, lo que significa que si la consulta no tiene ningún resultado vas a devolver `null`. He visto que en el finally cierras el ResultSet y el Statement, pero no cierras la conexión a base de datos nunca y eso es una mala práctica que te puede dar errores en muchas ocasiones ya que cada vez que ejecutas el método se abre una conexión se guarda en memoria hasta que pasa el [Garbage Collector](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recolector_de_basura). Intenta cerrar la conexión en el finally de esta forma: `acceDB.Close();`
Después del `if` en el que compruebas si hay algo en el ResultSet, si no vas a hacer nada, deberías borrar el `Else`vacío que has escrito.

Comment: ok voy a probar esta solucion

Comment: OK me parece que funciona bien creo que efectivamente acceDB.Close()

Comment: si olvide cerrar la conexion muchas Gracias

Comment: en el momento en que no se cerraba la conexion quedaba con incosistencias y parecia que era problema con los objetos pero no era que habia cerrado la conexion a la bd

Answer (score 2):

Devuelves taxCategory pero no siempre lo creas.
Solo creas taxCategory cuando rst.next() devuelve true pero cuando el resultado de la consulta está vacio rst.next() devuelve false y taxCategory no se crea. Debes decidir qué hacer cuando el resultado de la consulta es vacío.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu campo tax_category_id es tipo varchar, intenta poner tu taxId entre comillas.

Ahora en vez de utilizar Statement, intenta utilizar PreparedStatement, de la siguiente forma:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
preparedStatement = acceDB.prepareStatement(query);
rst=preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while( rst.next() ) {
taxCategory= new TaxCategory();
             taxCategory.setTaxCategoryId(rst.getInt("tax_category_id"));
             taxCategory.setTaxCategoryName(rst.getString("tax_category_name")); 
}
//Comprobamos que no venga vacío tu objeto
if(taxCategory != null && !taxCategory.getTaxCategoryName.equals(""){
//Aquí pones algo en caso de que no venga vacío
}
```

[Aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) te dejo la documentación